# Changing the height of an element to match the size of another element

Tags: html, css

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/227/

1. How can I change the height of `left`, and `right` based on the height of `middle` (which is dynamic and can change) using `HTML` and `CSS`?
2. If 1 is not possible then, how can I change the height of `left`, and `right` to cover the whole visible screen using `HTML`, and `CSS`?

Comment: With only `html` and/or `css` it's not possible, you will have to use `JavaScript` (or `jQuery`) to do so.

Comment: @Xlander is 2 also not possible with css and html?

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand what you've just said.

Comment: Can #2 in my question be done with just `html` and `css` ? or do we need `js` for that too?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DGImC try

Comment: CSS, Flexbox, see this: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/qIAwr

Comment: Ah ok. Yes via `css` it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 can't be done without Javascript.

Question 2 can be done with using

```
position:absolute;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
```

The `height:100%;` is optional but without `position:absolute;` it won't work. If you set `position:absolute;` you have to set `left:80%;` for your right side because otherwise it overlaps your left side.

Comment: could you please edit the jsfiddle to demonstrate what you are saying for part 2 ?

Comment: Yes, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/230/ I had to add a left:80%; on the right because otherwise it overlaps the left one due to position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Granted that this question is not tagged with javascript or specifically jQuery. If you *were* able to load jQuery you can match the height of the middle element easily.

```
var middleHeight = $('.middle').height();
$('.left, .right').height(middleHeight);
```